# Email HTML/CSS desktop and mobile imaging

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-email

I'm running into issues with my code for image swapping when viewing either desktop and mobile. It seems to be working fine for some platforms, but not working on Android mobile and some versions of Outlook. Can I get some assistance?

```
    <style>

.visible-mobile {
  display: none !important;
}

@media (max-width: 489px) {
  .visible-mobile {
    display: inline !important;
  }

  .hidden-mobile {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

</style>
```

And the content

```
<img src="https://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/839950/117069988/stock-photo-dog-listening-with-big-ear-117069988.jpg" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; border: none; height: auto;" alt="houdini" class="visible-mobile">

<img src="https://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/2997419/259670459/stock-photo-happy-dog-with-tongue-out-and-head-tilt-259670459.jpg" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; border: none; height: auto;" alt="houdini" class="hidden-mobile">
```

Comment: "Not working" is not a technical term. What isn't working and how? Does that markup show the problem?

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: HTML and CSS in emails has horrible support and consistency. Media queries are a long shot at best. As a rule of thumb if a technique would have been considered "advanced" on the web circa 2010, it's probably still a no-go in emails today.

Answer (score 1):

I have added a class

```
<style>

.visible-mobile {display: none !important;}
.hidden-mobile{display:none !important;} /* new class added*/

@media screen and (max-width:489px){
  .visible-mobile {
    display: block !important;
/* change inline to block */
  }

  .hidden-mobile {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

</style>
```

Desktop image stays as it is

```
<img src="https://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/839950/117069988/stock-photo-dog-listening-with-big-ear-117069988.jpg" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; border: none; height: auto;" alt="houdini" class="visible-mobile">
```

Mobile version has conditional statement for outlook.

Give the above changes a shot.

Cheers

Comment: Try changing `@media` to `@media screen and (max-width:489px)`

Comment: chris I updated my code so it should work now. Basically the mobile image should now show in all apart from Outlook. scoopzilla I added the correct media query as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. The problem is that you're attempting to call media queries in Outlook, which doesn't support them. Right now, very few email clients support this kind of HTML (Apple Mail, Outlook for Mac, and iOS Mail to name almost all of them).

For email, you need to write almost all CSS inline.

Comment: As someone who does a lot of email dev for work, I can't recommend Litmus enough. They take so much work out testing different email clients.

Comment: You don't need to do all inline CSS.

Comment: Outlook and Gmail both strip CSS out of the `<head>` element. So if you want your email to look good on more than just iOS mail, then yeah, you kinda do.

Comment: I disagree, but that is a matter of opinion, I guess.

Comment: This is isn't a matter of opinion. Gmail and Outlook do both in fact strip out the entire `<head>` element from your code, leaving only the inline styling behind. Gmail does it to prevent security issues with JavaScript. That's why we can't do responsive email for Gmail yet. Can you explain how any of that is subjective? If you're saying that there's a time and place for CSS in the `<head>`, then I would agree, but that code only works for specific email clients, like iOS mail and other browser based clients.

Comment: To clarify, I _do_ put media queries in my company's email marketing, but I make sure that the structure of the email doesn't rely on them. It's only for further enhancing the experience for users who are using browser-based clients. It's important to inline your crucial CSS, if you want broad support across all email clients.

Comment: I can do responsive email for gmail. It's not an opinion. I can absolutely code responsive emails that look good in Gmail with a `<style>` in . You just have to use the inline behavior `table [class=this]`

Comment: I remember when that technique surfaced in 2014. It's definitely a cool workaround, but support is limited for that within Google's email clients themselves. Last I checked, it only works on Gmail webmail and with gmail.com email addresses. Also, to correct my wording, I should've said we can't do _media queries_ in Gmail. "Responsive" design has been possible as long as `max-width` has been supported. Google did announce they're rollilng out more support for `<style>` and event external stylesheets though, so that's cool.

Comment: But you can [Gmail supported CSS](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css)

Comment: Yeah, I had edited my last comment to note that Google announced big changes in CSS support in September. I didn't know if they'd been fully rolled out or not yet. Pretty cool though! Anyway, back to the original issue — it appears as though he's testing for Outlook, so his audience is probably using it widely, and Outlook does require extensive inlining, even if Gmail is no longer a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<!--[if gte mso 9]>` wrappers around elements in conjunction with adding these elements to effectively add CSS support for Outlook. it's not perfect, and Outlook 2010 and 2013 are still problematic.

Also there's a tutorial [here](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/191-style-display-none-not-working-in-gmail-and-outlook-2013) in regards to this subject.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta property="og:title" content="*|MC:SUBJECT|*">
<title>*|MC:SUBJECT|*</title>
<style type="text/css">
  #outlook a{
   padding:0;
  }
  .ReadMsgBody{
   width:100%;
  }
  body{
   width:100% !important;
   min-width:100%;
   -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
   -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
  }
  .ExternalClass{
   width:100%;
  }
  td{
   border-collapse:collapse !important;
  }
  v*{
   behavior:url(#default#VML);
   display:inline-block;
  }
  .ExternalClass,.ExternalClass p,.ExternalClass span,.ExternalClass font,.ExternalClass td,.ExternalClass div{
   line-height:100%;
  }
    </style>
    </head>
```

Good luck! Email marketing is rewarding and evil.